# Matplotlib PDF plots don't respond to figsize

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like the following code to size subplots such that the resulting PDF is 5 inches wide and 8 inches tall. But no matter what I put in the `figsize` bit, the resulting file is 8 inches wide and 6 inches tall. What am I doing wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gs

fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(5,8))
fig.set_canvas(plt.gcf().canvas)

gs1 = gs.GridSpec(3,2)
gs1.update(wspace=0.4,hspace=0.4)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0,0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[0,1])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs1[1,0])
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs1[1,1])
ax5 = plt.subplot(gs1[2,:])

ax1.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6], 'k-')

fig.savefig("foo.pdf", format='pdf')
```

Oops---**edited** to add that I have also tried `fig.set_size_inches((5,8))` and this doesn't seem to have any effect either.

Comment: try `fig = plt.figure()`

Comment: Just to elaborate on what @tcaswell said, there's a difference between `plt.figure` and `plt.Figure`.  `plt.Figure` happens to be inside the pyplot namespace, but it's the "raw" class. You can certainly initialize it by itself (you'll also need to initialize a `FigureCanvas` for anything to work), but the figure won't be added to the pyplot state machine.  `plt.figure` is a factory function that creates a linked `Figure` and `FigureCanvas` instance and adds them to the pyplot figure manager.  If you want to use the `plt.*` methods, you have to use `plt.figure`.

Comment: So what's happening is that `fig = plt.Figure(...)` creates a new figure instance, but it's not added to the pyplot state machine.  Therefore, when you call `plt.subplot`, there's no "current" figure, so _another_ figure is created behind-the-scenes. (This is another reason to use figure methods directly: e.g. `fig.add_subplot` instead of `plt.subplot`)

Comment: @JoeKington ah, that makes sense.  I was trying to figure out why a) it was working at all without setting up the canvas and b) given a why it was ignoring the size.

Comment: @tcaswell - Yeah, I should have said "when you call `plt.gcf()` inside of `set_canvas`" instead of "when you call `plt.subplot`".  Apparently, two figure objects can share the same canvas...  Or that's what's happening here, at any rate.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks guys. :-) And thanks for the helpful explanation of what's happening under the hood, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find it more convenient to use `matplotlib.pyplot.figure`

Try configuring the figure width after you have created it with code like

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_figheight(5)
fig.set_figwidth(8)
```

I may have the dimensions transposed, but this works for me. Here's a complete example cribbed from the matplotlib documentation with modifications to the figure size. This also works with a `figsize` parameter to the figure() call.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_figheight(10)
fig.set_figwidth(12)
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
        linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)

ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
fig.savefig("myfig.png", dpi=600) # useful for hi-res graphics
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm selecting this as the answer, but for future Googlers, be sure to check out @tcaswell and @JoeKington discussion and explanation above---it was because I was calling the `Figure()` (class) when I should have been using `figure()` (factory function)...

Comment: Who would have thought. Go figure!